# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN not giving correct value

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following tables and relationships

[image]

Here are the sample data -

[image]

I tried the following query-

```
 SELECT project.*, SUM(schedule.amount) as sch_total, SUM(expense.amount) as expense_total, SUM(bill.amount) as bill_total from project 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schedule on project.project_id = schedule.project_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN site on project.project_id = site.project_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN expense on site.site_id = expense.site_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bill on site.site_id = bill.site_id 
GROUP BY project.project_id
```

This is the query result -

[image]

But "bill_total" should be 200, not 400. 
What did I miss in the query?

Comment: Please learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  `SELECT * ... GROUP BY` won't even execute in 99% of dbms system.

Comment: @Eric, In Mysql it works due to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY functionality https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by.

Comment: @Eric, could you please explain why this is not a proper GROUP BY?

Comment: All of those non-aggregated columns in * must be in `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expense table have multiple rows for same Id. That table must be aggregated first and then used in join -

```
SELECT project.*,
       SUM(schedule.amount) as sch_total,
       SUM(E.amount) as expense_total,
       SUM(bill.amount) as bill_total
FROM project 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schedule on project.project_id = schedule.project_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN site on project.project_id = site.project_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT site_id, SUM(expense.amount)amount
                   FROM expense 
                  GROUP BY site_id) E on site.site_id = expense.site_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bill on site.site_id = bill.site_id 
GROUP BY project.project_id
```

Comment: @s.k.paul khoob sbagata.